# Why does jQuery AJAX Post Content-Type=application/json to MVC Controller Action method result in null parameter

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-core, post

I have seen this question asked and answered before numerous times so my apologies for repeating it yet again. However, all those questions were asked and answered quite a while ago so I am not sure if the answers are relevant today with newer versions of ASP.NET Core MVC and jQuery.

I have a MVC controller method that accepts a class object parameter like so...
`public async Task<IActionResult> AffiliatedUsers(UserFacilityAccessDTO userAccessInfo)`

In response to a user action, I want to invoke this method from a JavaScript function.

```
$.ajax({
        url: location.origin + "/facility/affiliatedusers",
        method: "POST",
```

My data to POST is a well formed JSON object in a variable called `payload`.

Below are combinations of `contentType` and `data` values that work and do not work. I was hoping someone could help me understand the cases where it DOES NOT work.

This works when `contentType` is NOT SPECIFIED

```
$.ajax({
        url: location.origin + "/facility/affiliatedusers",
        method: "POST",
        data: payload
```

In my action method I found out the contentType (Request.ContentType) is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

But when I pass the data as follows...

```
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),  // MUST stringify to show up as JSON in body
```

I see the parameter to the action method is instantiated BUT none of the values are passed. i.e. Model Binding does not seem to have occurred. I read somewhere that ASP.NET Core 3.1 REQUIRES you to decorate the action method parameter with `[FromBody]` while passing JSON payload. When I do that even the parameter is not instantiated and I get the input parameter set to NULL.

I know I have a working solution but I am really curious as to why application/json payload is not working when everything I have read so far seem to indicate this is a walk in the park. Am I missing some simple yet crucial setup. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Kind Regards...

Comment: Can you share your `payload`? Because I can successfully bind, so the problem may be caused by your type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research and testing I found the root cause and would like to share this information to especially help someone new like myself.

First of all my payload had a Enum field. So the string to enum value conversion a problem. This can be solved by adding

```
.AddJsonOptions(config =>
                    {
                        // For jQuery ajax post with string values for enum this helps with conversion.
                        config.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
                    });
```

The next and the more important problem was since my application is a MVC web-app with Views NONE of my controllers are decorated with the `[ApiController]` attribute. It appears to me (I'm not as advanced as many other in this community to actually look into the Asp.Net Core framework code on github) that without this decoration the controller can only process `application\x-www-form-urlencoded` payload.

Thanks to @Yinqui for asking to see the payload in an attempt to help me. I hope atleast 1 other developer benefits from my finding.

Regards...